# re.sub match with first occurrence of bracketed characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to capture the first group of characters before one or more underscores or dashes in a string using `re.sub` in Python 3.7. My current function is:
 `re.sub(r'(\w+)[-_]?.*', r'\1', x)`.

Example strings:

```
x = 'CAM14_20190417121301_000'
x = 'CAM16-20190417121301_000'
```

Actual output:

```
CAM14_20190417121301_000
CAM16
```

Desired output:

```
CAM14
CAM16
```

Why is it working when there is a dash after the first group, but not an underscore? I also tried `re.sub(r'(\w+)_?.*', r'\1', x)` to try and force it to catch the underscore, but that returned the same result. I would like the code to be flexible enough to catch either.

Comment: Because `\w` includes underscores

Comment: Either `r'(\w*?)[-_]?.*'` or `r'([^\W_]+)[-_]?.*'` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches underscores, consider using this regex instead:

```
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[-_]?.*', r'\1', x)
```